# Spring @RequestBody and Jackson custom polymorphic deserialization

Tags: java, spring, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

Suppose I have some @RestController with a @PostMapping like this:

```
@PostMapping
public SomeResponse create(@RequestBody AbstractRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

and this `AbstractRequest` is an abstract class extended by `ConcreteOneRequest` and `ConcreteTwoRequest` classes:

```
@Value
@SuperBuilder
public ConcreteOneRequest extends AbstractRequest {
    String concreteOneUniqueField;
}

@Value
@SuperBuilder
public ConcreteTwoRequest extends AbstractRequest {
    String concreteTwoUniqueField;
}
```

Based on the above structure how can I use `@JsonTypeInfo` and/or `@JsonSubTypes` and/or `@JsonTypeResolver` to deserialize to the proper concrete class?

I have read the Jackson JavaDocs but I cannot understand their usage, I've also searched for specific examples but none I found matched my requirements.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In `AbstractRequest` you would add the following class-level annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = AbstractRequest.DISCRIMINATOR
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteOneRequest.class, name = FeeDefinitionType.Discriminator.TIERED),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteTwoRequest.class, name = FeeDefinitionType.Discriminator.STANDARD),
})
```

Where `@JsonTypeInfo` defines the polymorphic deserialization settings. Here, the important part is the `DISCRIMINATOR` property, which will be a String located in `AbstractRequest`.

It will tell Jackson to look for this key in the API request and deserialise the different object instances depending on its value.

You will define a getter for it, so the child classes can provide their discriminating values.

In `@JsonSubTypes` you indicate the list of possible sub-types for deserialization.

Here is a complete example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = AbstractRequest.DISCRIMINATOR
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteOneRequest.class, name = ConcreteOneRequest.getType()),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteTwoRequest.class, name = ConcreteTwoRequest.getType())
})
public abstract class AbstractRequest {
    public static final String DISCRIMINATOR = "type";

    abstract String getType();

}
```

So when `ConcreteOneRequest` returns `"CONCRETE_REQUEST_ONE"` on the `getType()`, Jackson will attempt to deserialise it when the `type` key in the API request has this value.